# Check if more imports are installed and install missing only python

Tags: python, python-module

I wonder if there is a way to check if all modules I am importing in the script are already installed and if some are not installed to install it.
For example,

```
import encodings
import json as json
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
```

if openpyxl is the only which is missing, install it only.
I know the way with requirements.txt, but that is not an option in this specific case.
I tried with try/catch, but it is only writing the message about missing package. I am not sure how to install package from the message.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Sounds like you are trying to re-invent pip or conda

Comment: I need this for a script which will be stored in one specific folder where I am allowed to place the script only, with no additional files like setup.py or requirements.txt

Comment: But what about the missing packages dependencies? And their dependencies?

Comment: I need to find the way to check if all packages are imported and if they are not, to install them. First idea is checking manually with some if/else but it's kind a spaghetti code. For now, I have try/catch block where catch block prints the name of missing package and how to install it.

Comment: So the code should be able to install its own dependencies ? Sure it may be convenient sometimes, but installing things without the user consent is often bad.